# handle cancel event on cancel using devexpress/dx-react-grid

Tags: reactjs, devexpress, devexpress-gridcontrol

We are using https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/grid/ in our application,
[image]

we just want handling event on click of cancel button in the row, also it should preserve the last saved value.In our scenario there is a dropdown in cell instead of text field. Please let us know if required more details.

```
<EditingState
      editingRowIds={editingRowIds}
      onEditingRowIdsChange={this.changeEditingRowIds.bind(this)}
      rowChanges={rowChanges}
      onCommitChanges={this.commitChanges.bind(this)}
     />
```